# Default docker swarm load distribution strategy within a single service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am new to `docker-swarm` and very much interested in knowing inner workings of how `docker-swarm` distributes the incoming requests for one single service.

For example, I deployed stack with one single service and 10 replicas across 2 nodes. when I brought up the node 5 containers did show up on node1 and other 5 on node2. Now, I make 10 http requests to the same service from 10 different browser instances, does each container end up with one request each? If it was a round-robin, I would think so. However,   I am not observing the same behavior from the stack that I have just deployed.

I brought up the stack with configuration above and made 10 requests. When I did that load was mire distributed than concentrated but only 7 of the containers got 10 requests and 3 were free.

This tells me that it is not even-distribution round robin. If not, what algorithm does docker services api follow to determine which container will serve the next request?

When I searched for inner workings of docker swarm, I ended up with article here : https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/

which is interesting look into ingress and routing mesh but still does not answer my original question.

Anyone?

Comment: It should be round-robin by default. What makes you conclude it isn't?

Comment: Can you share the stack config file